# SQL Count with zero values

Tags: sql, sql-server, count

I want to create a graph for my dataset for the last 24 hours.

I found a solution that works but this is pretty bad since the table I am outer joining cotains every single row in the DB since I am using the (now deprecated) "all" parameter in the group by.

Here is the solution that currently kind of works. 
First I declare the date intervals that is 24 hours back in time from now. I declare it twice so I can use it later in the procedure aswell.

```
Declare @StartDate datetime = dateadd(hour, -24, getdate())
Declare @StartDateProc datetime = dateadd(hour, -24, getdate())
Declare @EndDate datetime = getdate()
```

I populate the dates into a temp table including a special formated datetsring.

```
create table #tempTable
(
    Date datetime,
    DateString varchar(11)
)

while @StartDate <= @EndDate
begin
    insert into #tempTable (Date, DateString)  
    values (@StartDate, convert(varchar(8), @StartDate, 5) + '-' + convert(varchar(2), @StartDate, 108));

    SET @StartDate = dateadd(hour,1, @StartDate);
end
```

This gives me data that looks like this:

```
Date                              DateString
---------------------------------------------
2015-12-09 13:59:01.970           09-12-15-13
2015-12-09 14:59:01.970           09-12-15-14
2015-12-09 15:59:01.970           09-12-15-15
2015-12-09 16:59:01.970           09-12-15-16
```

So what I want is to join my dataset on the matching date string and show the date even if the matching rows is zero.

Here is the rest of the query

```
select
    Date = c.Date,
    Amount = sum(c.Amount)
from 
    DbTable a
outer apply 
    (select 
         Date = b.DateString,
         Amount = count(*)
     from 
         #tempTable b
     where
         convert(varchar(8), a.DateColumn, 5) + '-' + convert(varchar(2), a.DateColumn, 108) = b.DateString
     group by all
         b.DateString) c
where 
    a.SomeParameter = 'test' and
    a.DateColumn >= @StartDateProc and
    a.DateColumn <= @EndDate
group by
    c.Date

drop table #tempTable
```

Test to show actual data:

```
Declare @StartDate datetime = dateadd(hour, -24, getdate())
Declare @EndDate datetime = getdate()

select  
    dateString = convert(varchar(8),a.DateColumn,5) + '-' + convert(varchar(2),a.DateColumn, 108),
    Amount = COUNT(*)
from 
    DbTable a   

where
    a.someParameter = 'test' and
    a.DateColumn>= dateadd(hour, -24, getdate()) and
    a.DateColumn<= getdate()

group by 
    convert(varchar(8),a.DateColumn,5) + '-' + convert(varchar(2),a.DateColumn, 108)
```

First output rows:

```
dateString     Amount
09-12-15-14    1
09-12-15-15    1
09-12-15-16    1
09-12-15-17    3
09-12-15-18    1
09-12-15-22    3
09-12-15-23    2
```

As you can see here there is no data for the times from 19.00 to 21.00. This is how I want the data to be displayed:

```
dateString     Amount
09-12-15-14    1
09-12-15-15    1
09-12-15-16    1
09-12-15-17    3
09-12-15-18    1
09-12-15-19    0
09-12-15-20    0
09-12-15-21    0
09-12-15-22    3
09-12-15-23    2
```

Comment: Result set from one side of a join even if the other side isn't there sounds like a LEFT JOIN

Comment: Tried getting it to work with left join but I cant get it to show the 0 values.

Comment: Wow, `group by all` - I haven't seen this before. Microsoft recommends not to use this, it is deprecated.

Comment: yea, that's why I need another solution for this. I can see it outer applies serveral thousands of other rows since I feel (not sure) that the all parameter makes so includes every single row. This is also why i sum up the amount again in the select

Comment: added expected output

Comment: @stibay, what is the type of `a.DateColumn`?

Comment: @GiorgiNakeuri datetime

Comment: Restructured the question abit to try to make it clearer

Answer (score 3):

Normally, this would be approached with `left join` rather than `outer apply`.  The logic is simple:  keep all rows in the first table along with any matching information from the second.  This means put the dates table first:

```
select tt.DateString, count(t.DateColumn) as Amount
from #tempTable tt left join
     DbTable t
     on convert(varchar(8), t.DateColumn, 5) + '-' + convert(varchar(2), t.DateColumn, 108) = tt.DateString and 
        t.SomeParameter = 'test'
where tt.Date >= @StartDateProc and
      tt.Date <= @EndDate
group by tt.DateString;
```

In addition, your comparison for the dates seems overly complex, but if it works for you, it works.

Comment: what is missing is the NULL check on Sum function. like Sum (IsNull(t.Amount,0))

Comment: Hmm seems like this might be working with some editing. There is no field called Amount in the DB so guess this have be count(*). I also want to group by the DateString, so select tt.DateString and group by that. If it is any easier way to get just the date and the hour I would gladly appreciate that ;)

Comment: I also see that you are checking the date against tt.date and not against the date in the database? I see if I change this to t.DateColumn >= [at]StartDateProc and t.DateColumn <= [at]EndDate the procedure executes alot faster but it doesn't include the zero values.

Comment: It also seem to be adding a 1 even to the ones that are 0. Updated the question now.

Comment: You are seeing 1 instead of 0, because you probably changed to `count(*)`. This way you are also counting the row from temporary table with dates. Change it to depend on some column that comes from `LEFT JOINed` table, for example `count(t.id)`

Comment: Hmmm ok. Think I tested this but I will try this again tomorrow.

Comment: Seems to be almost working perfect now but for some reason the first row is always the wrong number. Seems to be always abit more than what it actually is. Also just have to change the tt.Date in the select and group by to tt.DateString.

Comment: Could it be with where I check the dates? In my other table I check on the datefield from the db but here its checking the dates towards the temp table

Answer (score 0):

The best bet here would be to use `DATETIME` type itself and not to lose the opportunity to use indexes:

```
Declare @d datetime = GETDATE()

;WITH cte1 AS(SELECT TOP 25 -1 + ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) h 
              FROM master..spt_values),
      cte2 AS(SELECT DATEADD(hh, -h, @d) AS startdate, 
                     DATEADD(hh, -h + 1, @d) AS enddate 
              FROM cte1)
SELECT c.startdate, c.enddate, count(*) as amount
FROM cte2 c
LEFT JOIN DbTable a ON a.DateColumn >= c.startdate AND 
                       a.DateColumn < c.enddate AND
                       a.SomeParameter = 'test'
GROUP BY c.startdate, c.enddate
```

Comment: Hmm that query takes very loong to execute around 7 to 8 seconds compared to the ~0.1 sec the other ones (and my group all) I also get very different results from the other methods.